# Cmake Error from openni2_camera

Tags: ros, catkin, openni2-camera, package, ros-groovy

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all.

Anybody knows how can I correct these?

```
   CMake Error at /usr/share/cmake-2.8/Modules/FindPkgConfig.cmake:266 (message):
  A required package was not found
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  /usr/share/cmake-2.8/Modules/FindPkgConfig.cmake:320 (_pkg_check_modules_internal)
  openni2_camera/CMakeLists.txt:9 (pkg_check_modules)


CMake Error at openni2_camera/CMakeLists.txt:26 (message):
  message called with incorrect number of arguments
```

Can't get past this one no matter what.

Thanks for any help.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/211912/cmake-error-from-openni2_camera/) by [psprox96](https://answers.ros.org/users/22776/psprox96/) on ROS Answers with karma: 97 on 2015-06-22

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If your Distribution does not have a OpenNi2-package, you need to build [OpenNi2](https://github.com/OpenNI/OpenNI2) from source and add a pkgconfig-file, e.g. /usr/local/lib/pkgconfig/openni2.pc:

```
prefix=/usr/local/OpenNI2
includedir=${prefix}/Include
libdir=${prefix}/Bin/Arm-Release

Name: openni2
Description: OpenNI2
Version: 2.2.0.33
Cflags: -I${includedir}
Libs: -L${libdir} -lOpenNI2
```

---

Originally posted by [Humpelstilzchen](https://answers.ros.org/users/21851/humpelstilzchen/) with karma: 1504 on 2015-06-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [psprox96](https://answers.ros.org/users/22776/psprox96/) on 2015-06-23**:
Thanks! It works! I installed:

```
sudo apt-get install libopenni2-dev libopenni2-0
```

And corrected the cmakelists.txt line 26 to:
message ("${PC_OPENNI2_LIBRARY_DIRS}")

**Comment by [Rufus](https://answers.ros.org/users/34739/rufus/) on 2021-03-17**:
Alternatively, you can run

```
rosdep install --from-paths . --ignore-src --rosdistro <your distro>
```

to automatically install required dependencies